# Use-Case Of Directives In Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

I have made an angular element directive for both header and footer. Header directive contains cart element functionality and my accounts feature. Is there anything wrong about making it as a directive?
Is it the angular way or best practice of using the power of directive?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Angular 1.5 introduces the concept of component, which is a simpler way to write a directive serving as a graphical component. You might use that instead of a raw directive.

Comment: As angular 1.5 introduced components, you might want to have a look at these as well. They should ease a later translation to angular 2. They are pretty much like directives that are created with require: "E". So they might fit better for header and footer than a directive does. Read about components here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 1.5 introduced the Component (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) which mostly serves as a replacement for a directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). At the very least, you can achieve most of the things (I'm not entirely sure if it serves as a complete replacement) that a directive can do. Components seem to be more structured and is more conducive to component based development (with a name like 'component' that shouldn't be too surprising :P).

If you need to write something that would be the equivalent of an Angular directive restricted to `'A'` then you should probably still use a directive, otherwise for most other cases, writing a component will serve as a better idea. I like to think of a directive as a "decoration" as of Angular 1.5.

As for your question of "is it wrong to use directives" - the answer is "no, probably not, but using a component is a more accepted practice for most things with Angular development these days".

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! My thought of using directive was mostly to use it as something that needs to get bonded with the Dom! But it helps.